# Codeblock Expression for ArcGIS with Python

Tags: python, arcgis, calculated-field

I have problems with an expression for the Field Calculation in ArcGIS 10.2. I already tried the code in Python and it worked out but with the small changes I had to do for applying the code in ArcGIS it wont work.

`PGIS_TXT` is a column of strings as shown below, the first number is the numerator of a parcel which I want to extract of that string with a Python expression.

```
PGIS_TXT = ["31\c\u\n\2","22","1","134","23\c\u\n\1"] 


import re
def getnumerator(PGIS_TXT):

if (len( PGIS_TXT ) > 3):
    p=map(int, re.findall('\d+', PGIS_TXT ))
    b=p[:-1]
    return b
else:
    b= int(PGIS_TXT)
    return b
```

those numbers should then stored in my column `flur_za`:

```
flur_za = getnumerator(!PGIS_TXT!)
```

The result should be:

```
[31, 22, 1, 134, 23]
```

I get a standard error `"Error 999999"` and the message `"The field is not nullable [flur_za]"`

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
def getnumerator(PGIS_TXT):

import re
if len(PGIS_TXT) > 3:
    p = map(str, re.findall('\d+',PGIS_TXT))
    z=p[:1]
    b=int(''.join(z))
else:
    if len(PGIS_TXT)==3:
        b=int(PGIS_TXT[:3])
    else:
        if len(PGIS_TXT)==2:
            b= int(PGIS_TXT[:2])
        else:
            if len(PGIS_TXT)==1:
                b= int(PGIS_TXT[:1])
return b
```

I think the problem was within the first if-condition. I get a list with integer values with the map method, but i needed an integer value. The .join method helped to get rid of the list.